# VSTO excel paste failed

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, paste

I am trying to copy from one workbook with 5 sheets. Then paste content from all 5 sheets into a different workbook sheet one.

The first paste is successful, then it try to paste the second sheet it generate error:

> The information cannot be pasted because the copy area and the paste area are not the same 
>   size or shape. Try one of the following:
>
> - Click a single cell, and then paste.
> - Select a rectangle that's the same size and shape, and then paste.

Following is my code:

```
int rowCount = 0;

app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
sourceBook = app.ActiveWorkbook;

targetBook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
targetSheet = targetBook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing);
targetSheet.Name = "Merge Result";


foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in sourceBook.Worksheets)
{

    Excel.Range workSheetRange = sheet.UsedRange;
    workSheetRange.Copy(Type.Missing);
    Excel.Range pasteStartCell = (Excel.Range)targetSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 1];
    Excel.Range pasteEndCell = (Excel.Range)targetSheet.Cells[rowCount + workSheetRange.Rows.Count, workSheetRange.Columns.Count];
    Excel.Range pasteArea = targetSheet.get_Range(pasteStartCell, pasteEndCell);
    pasteArea.Select();
    targetSheet.Paste(Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    rowCount = rowCount + workSheetRange.Rows.Count;

}
```

I have also tried with

```
Excel.Range pasteStartCell = (Excel.Range)targetSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 1];
pasteStartCell.Select()
```

then paste, same error message.

Does anyone know which part I went wrong?

Comment: Hi jbarker2160: thank you for the suggestion I have tried with Range.PasteSpecial but still get the same error. Do I need to clear the clipboard before the second copy?

Comment: Dont post changes that dont work as an answer - Edit your question with updates is the correct process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using `.Select()`  instead try `Range.PasteSpecial()`.

Comment: Hi jbarker2160: Thank you for the answer. But I have tried following code it still give me the same error message.

Comment: Hi jbarker2160: thank you for the suggestion I have tried with Range.PasteSpecial but still get the same error. Do I need to clear the clipboard before the second copy?

Comment: After looking at your code more closely, the problem is that you're trying to paste and entire sheet into a part of another sheet.  You need to select only the data you wish to copy and copy and paste that.